# how to fade in fade out on when div is loaded in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have code to fade in fade out on button click but i want that when the text loads it should fade in or fade how to do this instead of button click

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Fading JavaScript Example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
<div id="fade">Fading JavaScript Example</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="button" onclick="fadeEffect.init('fade', 1)">Fade In</div>
    <div class="button floatright" onclick="fadeEffect.init('fade', 0)">Fade Out</div>
</div>
<p>For more information visit <a href="http://www.leigeber.com">leigeber.com</a>.       </p>
  </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can use `<body onload="">`:

```html
...
</head>
<body onload="fadeEffect.init('fade', 1)">
...
```

[Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp)

#### Or same with jQuery `$(document).ready();`:

```html
...
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('#fademein').fadeIn( 1000 );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
<span id="fademein" style="display: none">Will fade in smoothly</span>
```

[Read more here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)